# Can't call float() in if statement

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement

I am trying to convert a string in a float within an `if` statement. Now I can call it on the actual `if` line but not inside of it:

```
rates = "1"
if float(rates) == 1:    #This works
    print "Hi"
if rates == "1":
    float(rates) += 1    #This doesn't work
```

Now the error is that the function (`float()`) could not be called from within the `if` statement for the second `if` statement. Why is this happening? Here is the error:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/Anthony/Desktop/Python/PyQt/Pratical_Programs/Stack_Overflow.py
  File "C:/Users/Anthony/Desktop/Python/PyQt/Pratical_Programs/Stack_Overflow.py", line 5
    float(rates) += 1    #This doesn't work
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the += operator is the increment operator. It attempts to increment the operand to the left of it by the operand to the right, in this case by 1.

But that's syntactically illegal if the left operand is a function call.

The first call worked because the == operator is not an assignment operator but a comparison operator.

Answer (score -2):

You state that the second section doesn't work, and i believe it's because you need to do:

```
 if rates == "1":
    int(float(rates)) == 1
```

Comment: As `int(float(rates)) == 1` is equvalent to `True` I simplify your code: `if rates ==1: True`.